# Rendering dozens of SVGs without lag on React Native?

Tags: react-native, svg

I need to display dozens of fairly complex SVGs on screen, on a React native chat app.

Each SVG represents an avatar with 3 shades, whose color I change through code to fit the user's preferences.

[image]

[image]

Because I am changing colors dynamically, I am currently displaying the SVGs as components in a `Webview`.

This works fine, but when I have a dozen of those on-screen (for example inside a busy chat room), I am having some serious performance issues.

What would be a good approach to keep both my colorized SVGs AND performance?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg ?

Comment: I did. That's what I use for SVGs that do not need coloring. It doesn't let me edit the code of the SVG to change the color of each group as I need though - which makes me go back to the Webview.

Comment: Sadly svg support on the mobile worls is still pretty bad

Comment: Wait, actually I checked again and I completely missed on the `SvgCss` component. I had only seen `SvgCssUri`. With that one, I managed to feed my modified SVG string, and performance definitely improved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [react-native-svg](http://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg)'s SvgCss improved perfomance tremendously.

Comment: Where can i read about its performance improvements ? I dont see mentioning in docs.